# Use a custom name for the inside of array xml in a WebMethod

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service using `WebMethod` with the following signature;

```vb
<WebMethod(Description:="...")>
Public Function MyWebService(..., foods as Integer(), ...) as ...
```

Which looks like the following in the SOAP request;

```xml
...
<foods>
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
</foods>
...
```

For various reasons I believe it would be better if the `int` was instead `food_id` like below;

```xml
...
<foods>
  <food_id>1</food_id>
  <food_id>2</food_id>
</foods>
...
```

So my question is; is there a way to hint to .NET that this is what I'm after?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Use [`XmlArrayItemAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks John, I'll take a look at that. I am aware that it's not ideal to still be working with asmx, but fortunately in this case I'm just making a quick change to a legacy system.